# Given $k$ points in $n$-dimensional space, is there always a continuous $n-1$ surface that can divide the points into two arbitrary groups?

Tags: general-topology, vectors, transformation, separable-spaces

Say we have $k$ points in set $P\mid x_i\in\mathbb{Z}^n$, such that $k=\mathcal{O}(n!)$. We now arbitrarily divide the points into two sets, $A$, $B$. Note that $A\cup B = P$ and $A \cap B = \varnothing$.

Is there *always* $n-1$ dimensional surface in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that perfectly separates these two sets of points? Is there some transformation $T:\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^n}$, such that this $n-1$ dimensional surface is a function $f(\vec x)$? If so is it always possible to find this function?

I know this is similar to the idea of **SVN** machine learning, but I'm more interested in the theoretical ideas about existence of these divides.

Comment: In general in dimension $n>3$, there is room for a *curve* (i.e. 1-dimensional object) to do basically anything you can imagine. However, what do you mean by *separate* here?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier you're right, I meant $n-1$ dimensional surface (if that's the correct term)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As quasi pointed out, the condition $n\geq 2$ is necessary.

We use induction on $n$. The statement holds for $n=2$. Indeed, connect the points in one of the two sets, say $A$, to make a closed, simple curve (no self-intersection). Use segments connecting the points in an appropriate order to obtain such a curve. (We don't want any Peano nonsense.) 
If a point of $B$ happens to be on this curve, make a detour. 
Then create a tube around this curve: using segments parallel to the ones in the curve, very close to the curve on both sides. If you pick these parallel segments close enough, only points in $A$ are inside this closed tube. Then cut the tube by breaking one of the pipes and seal the ends. That is, pick a pair of segments perpendicular to the pipe connecting the two walls of the pipe, and delete the part of the two walls between the segments. Then the walls of the broken tube and the two seals together form a polyhedron that separates $A$ from $B$.

Now let $n>2$ and assume that the statement holds for $n-1$. 
There are finitely many points given, so there are finitely many (ordered) pairs of them. Each pair $(P,Q)$ specifies a vector: the vector $\overrightarrow{PQ}$. 
Pick a vector $\overrightarrow{v}$ that is not parallel to any of these, and let $H$ be the hyperplane ($(n-1)$-dimensional subspace) with normal vector $\overrightarrow{v}$. 
Project all the points onto $H$. Solve the problem in $H$ for the projected points (induction hypothesis):  an $(n-2)$-dimensional surface $S$ does the job.
Then $S'= \{s+c\overrightarrow{v} \mid s\in S, c\in \mathbb{R}\}$ is a good solution for the original points.

Comment: But what happens if two conflicting points overlap on the projection? Can that happen?

Comment: I picked the vector carefully enough so that it cannot happen. Check the answer again!

Comment: You need to assume $n \ge 2$. Also, you should discuss the base case $n=2$,

Comment: Yes but both of these are trivial.

Comment: In this context, isn't the hypersurface required to be connected? If so, the claim fails for $n=1$, if $k > 2$

Comment: I think that was how the author meant it. Otherwise, the problem is not very interesting.

Comment: Is the truth of the claim for the base case $n=2$ self-evident? I don't see it at a glance. If you can edit your answer so as to include an outline of how that case gets handled, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: All right. Thank you for your observation, I will do it.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Looks good! (+1)

Comment: Given the case $n=2$, higher dimensions follow immediately by projecting the points onto any 2-dimensional plane for which all the projections are distinct. Now you can choose a curve in this plane that separates the projections of sets $A$ and $B$, and your final surface is the orthogonal extension of this curve back into $\mathbb R^n$ (its "un-projection"). Let me know if I have not made myself clear, and I will try to hand-wave some more.

Answer (score 0):

Solve the poisson equation,
$\Delta u = f$
with $f$ consisting of delta function sources at points in $A$ and sinks at points in $B$. The zero set of the solution $u$ separates the points. One should be able to prove that either this zero set is smooth, or the zero set associated with arbitrarily small perturbations of the points is smooth, by using elliptic regularity and Sard's theorem.

You could also compute the sensitivity of the surface to movement of the points with the implicit function theorem.

The surface may consist of several disconnected components though.

Comment: But if you allow disconnected components, the problem becomes trivial. Just put a small ball around every point of $A$. Actually, this can be fixed to a connected solution as in the 2-dimensional case, see my answer.

Comment: Hmm true. This could be remedied by connecting all points in $A$ with curves, and similar for $B$, then making $f$ a line source on the curves, rather than point sources in the points